# Exoplayer demo stuck in buffering state

Tags: exoplayer, mpeg

I'm using the Google Exoplayer demo app to test some h264 streams that I've transcoded. All the files I have created stall in the demo app in the buffering state. No errors are thrown in Android Studio and everything appears to be working correctly other than the stalled player.

I found a reference to what appears to be my exact problem here (https://exoplayer.dev/debugging-playback-issues.html). It references two flags that need to be set FLAG_DETECT_ACCESS_UNITS and FLAG_ALLOW_NON_IDR_KEYFRAMES to fix my issue, but I can not find any reference on how to accomplish this in the Exoplayer demo app (https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.